# Should JavaScripts for Google Maps, reCAPTCHA. etc. be referenced separately or concatenated in main.js?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, gulp, build-system

I have a website with a large number of pages. Is it best to include third-party JavaScripts such as Google Maps, reCAPTCHA, etc. within my Gulp build system that concatenates all JavaScripts into one or should each JavaScript be referenced using a separate `script` tag from Google's server?

It seems ideal to have everything in `main.js` to reduce the number of HTTP requests. The problem with this is if NPM packages aren't updated frequently and Google changes their code for Maps or reCAPTCHA, it could be outdated.

On the other hand, loading Google Maps or reCAPTCHA via a separate `script` tag seems to make sense on the pages that needed and it also will pull in the latest version.

Any advice and tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As long as you are loading those scripts with `defer` it shouldn't have too much impact on the page loading time if you keep them separate...if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Exactly as @abagshaw wrote: _"use the `async` and `defer` parameters in the script tags"_ ([reference](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param))

Comment: AFAIK with http/2 the multiple requests issue is not such a big deal. As Maps and reCAPTCHA are regularly used there is a good chance another site has cached the scripts to they can be fetched from cache. You might also consider the performance impact that comes with a single large bundle (initial load time for instance).

Comment: Note http/2 multiple requests is not a big deal when requests are sent to the same server, which is not applicable in this case